# JSch SFTP security with session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, public-key, key-pair

I use JSch with private key to FTP file

```
jsch.addIdentity(privatekeyfile);
Session session = jsch.getSession("user", "example.com", 22);    
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
```

Line 3 is in question. Without this line, JSch does not work.

My question is:
Will line 3 make SFTP transfer insecure?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Disabling the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option will make the connection less secure than having the option enabled, because it will let you connect to remote servers without verifying their SSH host keys. If the option is enabled, you will only be able to connect to servers which keys are known to your SSH client.

You will have to decide what that means for your specific use case - are the servers you are connecting on a private, local network or do you connect over the internet? Is this a testing or production environment?

When in doubt, it is better to err on the side of more security. I would recommend enabling `StricktHostKeyChecking` and using the [`setKnownHosts` method](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setKnownHosts(java.lang.String)) to provide a file which contains the remote host keys.

Comment: `ssh-keyscan -t rsa localhost` produces something: # localhost SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
localhost ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDfkfoFN+oakKAvx2meT90jom1oRdBevPFP/2A+tN4+

Comment: In that case, your known_hosts file should contain the following line:
`abc.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDfkfoFN+oakKAvx2meT90jom1oRdBevPFP/2A+tN4+`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will make the connection (and the transfer) less secure. Particularly, it makes the connection open to [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

You should never set the `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no`, unless you do not care about security (such as when connecting within a private network).

It's not true that *"Without this line, JSch does not work"*. You just have to make your code accept the expected server's host key. Either via the [`setKnownHosts`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setKnownHosts-java.lang.String-) or the [`setHostKeyRepository`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setHostKeyRepository-com.jcraft.jsch.HostKeyRepository-) methods.

For examples, see [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)

---

You can read my article on [verifying the host key](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key) to understand its importance. It's about WinSCP SSH/SFTP client, but it's generally true for any SSH client/library.