# Ingesting data from remote SFTP server using JSch with public/private key authentication. Any examples?

Tags: java, scala, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch library to create and manage "secure FTP" connection in Scala. Can someone show example using public/private key in configuration of `session`?

Right now I'm doing this

```
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
```

This exposes the secure connection for unauthorized hits over maintained session which, obviously, I don't want for security reasons.

How can I set private/public key mechanism in my code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StrictHostKeyChecking` has nothing to do with private/public key authentication. It's about host key verification. Though you are right that you should not set the option to `no`.

See [JSch SFTP security with session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30178936/850848)

---

For the actual public/private key authentication, see [Can we use JSch for SSH key-based communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4932005/850848)

Though note that the accepted answer wrongly sets the `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no`. So do not copy that part.

Comment: Okay, that's helpful of you. :)