# Execute a list of commands from an ArrayList using JSch exec in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, exec, jsch

Using JSch "exec" channel, I connect to a remote server and execute a command. What I can't do is to execute a list of commands stored in `ArrayList`. I use for loop to pass each element to `.setCommand(elem);` but for some odd reason, only the last command gets executed.

```
ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
lists.add("hostname");
lists.add("df -l");
Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");

for (String elem : lists){
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(elem);
}
```

Full Code

```
public class Exec{
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    try {
      JSch jsch=new JSch();

      String host=null;
      if(arg.length>0){
        host=arg[0];
      }
      else{
        host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                         System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                         "@localhost"); 
      }
      String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
      host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);


      UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
      session.setUserInfo(ui);
      session.connect();

      ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
        lists.add("hostname");
        lists.add("df -l");
      Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");

      for (String elem : lists){
          ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(elem);
      }

      channel.setInputStream(null);

      ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

      channel.connect();

      byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
      while(true){
        while(in.available()>0){
          int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
          if(i<0)break;
          System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if(channel.isClosed()){
          if(in.available()>0) continue; 
          System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
          break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
      }
      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return passwd; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
      Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
      int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
             str,
             "Warning", 
             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
             JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
             null, options, options[0]);
       return foo==0;
    }

    String passwd;
    JTextField passwordField=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(20);

    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){
      Object[] ob={passwordField}; 
      int result=
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
                                      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        passwd=passwordField.getText();
        return true;
      }
      else{ 
        return false; 
      }
    }
    public void showMessage(String message){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
    final GridBagConstraints gbc = 
      new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,
                             GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                             GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                             new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
    private Container panel;
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo){
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
      gbc.gridy++;

      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

      JTextField[] texts=new JTextField[prompt.length];
      for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        if(echo[i]){
          texts[i]=new JTextField(20);
        }
        else{
          texts[i]=new JPasswordField(20);
        }
        panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
      }

      if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, 
                                       destination+": "+name,
                                       JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
         ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
        for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
          response[i]=texts[i].getText();
        }
        return response;
      }
      else{
        return null;  // cancel
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that it's not "JSch exec channel". The shell and exec channels are integral part of the SSH protocol itself. They are not a features of the JSch library. It just implement them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call the `setCommand` multiple times. The "exec" channel can run a single "command" only.

But on most systems/shells, the "command" can actually include multiple commands.

A syntax will depend on your system/shell. Semicolons work usually:

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("hostname ; df -l");
```

Some servers/shells also allow newline.

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("hostname\ndf -l");
```

On *nix servers, you can also use `&&` to make the following commands be executed only when the previous commands succeeded:

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("hostname && df -l");
```

See also [Multiple commands through JSch shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5831594/850848#52399279).

---

Another option is to open a new channel for each command. Note that you can have multiple channels over a single SSH session. You do not have to reconnect for each channel/command.