# Get output of a specific command only in JSch shell channel

Tags: java, shell, jsch

I am trying to get the output of a shell script in java using JSch. Executing a `sudo` admin command and get the output of a script.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

String host="myhost";
StringBuilder command1= new StringBuilder();
String userName = "root";
String password="password";

try{

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, 22);

    session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected");

    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("ls");
    commands.add("sudo myadmincmd");
    commands.add("cd /logs");
    commands.add("my script...");
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell"); 
    channel.connect();
    channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

    OutputStream os = channel.getOutputStream();
    PrintStream shell = new PrintStream(os, true);

    for (String cmd : commands) {
        shell.println(cmd);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    }
    shell.println("exit");
    shell.close();

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
*ADMINSHELL* :/home/abcd # cd /logs
*ADMINSHELL* :/logs # 
*ADMINSHELL* :/logs # my script...
....
output goes here...
....
```

How can I get the output of only this ADMINSHELL? For example I only need the final output. I tried using a check as below,

```
for (String cmd : commands) {
    if(cmd.startsWith("for script")){
        shell.println(cmd);
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

But this time I am getting some permission denied issues. I need only the output of the last script.

```
....
output goes here...
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the output to some buffer/string. Then parse out and print only the part you want.
See [How to get jsch shell command output in String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25789245/850848).

---

There's no other way to separate output of individual commands. From an SSH client perspective, the shell is just a black box with input/output. There's no structure. The "shell" should not be use to automate command execution. You should use the "exec" channel. See also [What is the difference between the 'shell' channel and the 'exec' channel in JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6770206/850848#56713547).

In the "exec" channel, you execute each command independently, so you won't have problems separating their output.  See [How to read JSch command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6902386/850848)

---

Anyway, if you want to stick with your suboptimal "shell" solution, it helps, when you print some delimiter before and after the script like:

```
echo ---begin---
/.../myscript.sh   
echo ---end---
```