# How to store multiple lines of command output to a variable using JSch

Tags: java, linux, jsch

So, I have a nice bit of code (that I'm struggling to understand), that allows me to send a command to my server, and get one line of response. The code works, but I would like to get multiple lines back from the server.

The main class is:

```
JSch jSch = new JSch();
MyUserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
String Return = "Error";
try {
    String host = "Username@HostName";
    String user = host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
    host = host.substring(host.indexOf('@') + 1);
    Session rebootsession = jSch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    rebootsession.setPassword(Password);
    rebootsession.setUserInfo(ui);
    rebootsession.connect();
    Channel channel = rebootsession.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(Command);
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    channel.connect();
    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0) break;
            Return = new String(tmp, 0, i);
        }
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    rebootsession.disconnect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
return Return;
```

I would like to be able to return multiple lines from the first class.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what you want back? Can you put an example?

Comment: The answer below solved the issue, however an example would be when i used the lshw command, it only returned a single line, not the entire config. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the output to the `Return` variable, instead of overwriting it in each pass:

```
Return += new String(tmp, 0, i);
```